# Dear imgui, How to create buttons with icons and text？

Tags: imgui

I want to create a button with icons and text in the window of dear imgui, but I did not find the relevant interface.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sl9Oz.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 6):

You might take a look on the iconfont

https://github.com/juliettef/IconFontCppHeaders

[image]

Comment: I had no idea this is a thing, this is awesome